# Cannot update net_transport to TCP in SQL Server

Tags: sqoop, named-pipes, sql-server-config-manager

I have SQL Server 2012 installed and I need to update the net-transport type from named pipes to tcp protocol. I do that in the SQL server configuration manager and restart the services. Yet, on running

```
select connectionproperty('net_transport') as net_transport,
connectionproperty('protocol_type') as pt,
connectionproperty('auth_scheme') as sh,
connectionproperty('local_net_address') as lna,
connectionproperty('local_tcp_port') as tcport,
connectionproperty('client_net_address') as cna
from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

It gives me net_transport type as named pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep tcp/ip only enabled and disable 'named pipes' this will change to tcp/ip

Comment: Hey, I tried this but when I run the query it still returns named pipes.